# Regex Beginner Formatting

Tags: regex

I have a Regex question. How do I Capture every instance of a word ‘yellow’ that is not surrounded by quotation marks?

Comment: In what language? And what is your sample text?

Comment: In general terms as I am learning Regex and getting practice.

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/questions/477463/is-it-possible-to-use-not-in-a-regular-expression-in-textmate

Comment: Read about [negative lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: As well as the word not being surrounded by quotation marks, you probably do not want to match words such as 'yellowtail' or 'yellowthroat'. A common safeguard against that is to surround the word with word boundaries (`\byellow\b`), which prevents 'y' from being preceded by a word character or 'w' being followed by a word character. If your regex engine supports lookaheads and lookbehinds you can write `(?<!['"])\byellow\b(?!['"])`, where `(?<!['"])` is a *negative lookbehind* and `(?!['"])` is a negative lookahead...

Comment: ...If lookarounds are not supported you just want to confirm 'yellow' is not preceded or followed by a quote you can write `(?:^|[^'"])\byellow\b(?:$|[^'"])`. This matches `'yellow'` if it is either at the beginning of the string or is preceded by a character other than a single or double-quote, and is either at the end of the string or is followed by a character other than a single or double-quote. You also need to ask yourself why you need to "capture" 'yellow' as opposed to simply confirming that where it appears it is not surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything with RE, but sometimes trying to get the perfect RE gives you a strange unreadable expression that only a few will understand or catch a corner case that affects certain tools. So I prefer to stick with only the basic parts.

The regular expression for 'yellow' is `yellow`.
The regular expression for not quotes is `[^"]`

So I would say the simplest version is:

```
[^"]yellow[^"]
```

But then you may start thinking of edge cases. Like the word may appear at the beginning or end of a line. So if we are not trying to be clever and just do this brute force we can check for yellow at the beginning and end of line.

Note if it does not have " because of line boundaries (I am assuming that we don't need to check for quotes the other end because it will not be surrounded by quotes :-)

Beginning of line anchor is `^` and end of line anchor is `$`

```
^yellow       Check for yellow at the beginning
yellow$       Check for yellow at end of line
```

Combine all these options with `|` (or)

```
[^"]yellow[^"]|^yellow|yellow$
```

But that is going to catch 'yellow' in the middle of a word. Not sure how many words have yellow in the middle. But if this is a short English text, I would not worry about it. If this was a large blob of text I could depend on the situation.

Sure you can do it more compressed. But do you want to?

Now you have to think about the specifics of the tool you are using and what needs to be escaped.

Comment: If you make `[^?]` optional it will match `"yellow"` because the optional expression is ignored.

Comment: That didn't solve it